# Konvajs: drag stage with some momentum like Google Maps

Tags: konvajs

What would be the best way to drag a stage with some momentum like you have on Google Maps, where after releasing the mouse, the stage still moves until it stops?

I already have a draggable stage and I have some movement restrictions:

```
stage.on("dragmove", function(evt) {
  // read absolute position
  const oldAbs = xaxis.absolutePosition();

  xaxis.absolutePosition({
   x: oldAbs.x,
   y: 0
  });
});
```

Could I add some kind of animation/tween on stage dragend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the speed of the movement of a node to apply additional animation.

The simplest implementation can be like this:

```js
let lastPos;
let speed = {};
stage.on('dragstart', () => {
  lastPos = stage.position();
});

stage.on('dragmove', () => {
  const pos = stage.position();
  speed.x = pos.x - lastPos.x;
  speed.y = pos.y - lastPos.y;
  lastPos = pos;
})

stage.on('dragend', () => {
  stage.to({
    x: stage.x() + speed.x * 5,
    y: stage.y() + speed.y * 5
  })
})
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/kibidomuge/edit?html,js,output

You may need to find a better way to calculate the speed for better UX. For example you can use https://hammerjs.github.io/ library on Stage container.